# Retrieve data from specified http-service in xsl PDF template

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm using orbeon 3.8 and have the first version of [print-pdf-template.xml](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/e1e44590bb41ceaa6480a1156c8904d1b4a06341/src/resources/apps/fr/print/print-pdf-template.xsl)

And I have following problem, when I'm using http-services to fill xforms:select elements, everything works fine, until I'm trying to get pdf version of form, as I can understand the code below

```
<xsl:when test="local-name($control) = 'select1'">
   <!-- Other single-selection controls: just use label -->
   <field acro-field-name="'{$field-name}'" value="'{$control-resources/item[value = $control-value]/label}'"/>
</xsl:when>
```

is trying to get label value from resources which form has, and not from http-service. And surely there's no data in form.xhtml with such value.

When I'm filling xforms:element with static fields everything displays in PDF as it should be. If I would change

```
<field acro-field-name="'{$field-name}'" value="'{$control-resources/item[value = $control-value]/label}'"/>
```

to

```
<field acro-field-name="'{$field-name}'" value="'{$control-value}'"/>
```

then PDF will show the value of selected item.

As I understand data for print-pdf-template.xsl is described in print-pdf-template.xpl, which determine which processor to use for data transformation.

So I'm wondering what best way to retrieve label data from http-service, which fills xforms:select element with data, in PDF template?

Is it possible to retrieve data without changing processor code?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed starting with [this commit](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/052f3825c5095bc6e8625d1bd86d35085b6888f4) (other subsequent commits are also involved) from September 2, 2011.

So this is not a trivial fix and there is no simple answer. From here you could:

1. patch your build based on those commits (not necessarily trivial)
2. upgrade to a nightly build
3. wait for the next stable release